# how to group by with a sql that has multiple subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, fastreport

I am trying to add a group by SC_FRAMES.GROUPPRODUCTTYPE to this statement:

```
SELECT
  SC_JOBS.CREATIONDATE,

  (SELECT SUM(SC_JOBS.GROSSEXCLVAT) FROM SC_JOBS WHERE SC_FRAMES.GROUPPRODUCTTYPE = 'ABC'    AND SC_FRAMES.JOBID = SC_JOBS.JOBSID AND SC_JOBS.INVOICEDATE < '1990-01-01') AS Product1,

  (SELECT SUM(SC_JOBS.GROSSEXCLVAT) FROM SC_JOBS WHERE SC_FRAMES.GROUPPRODUCTTYPE = 'XYZ'    AND SC_FRAMES.JOBID = SC_JOBS.JOBSID AND SC_JOBS.INVOICEDATE < '1990-01-01') AS Product2 

FROM
  SC_JOBS
INNER JOIN
  SC_FRAMES ON SC_FRAMES.JOBID = SC_JOBS.JOBSID
WHERE
  SC_JOBS.CREATIONDATE BETWEEN :StartDate AND :EndDate
ORDER BY
  SC_JOBS.CREATIONDATE
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: What are you trying to group by?

Comment: product type - apologies I could of been a little clearer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a query like this:

```
SELECT f.GROUPPRODUCTTYPE,
       MIN(j.CREATIONDATE),
       SUM(case when j.INVOICEDATE < '1990-01-01' then j.GROSSEXCLVAT else 0
           end) as Product1
FROM SC_JOBS INNER j JOIN
     SC_FRAMES f
     ON f.JOBID = j.JOBSID
WHERE j.CREATIONDATE BETWEEN :StartDate AND :EndDate
GROUP BY f.GROUPPRODUCTTYPE
ORDER BY min(j.CREATIONDATE);
```

It replaces the subqueries with conditional aggregation, based on the invoice date.

Comment: This is perfect. Just one thing is the 'order by' stops the script running with the following msg: Engine Code    : 335544569
Engine Message :
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Invalid expression in the ORDER BY clause (not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause)

Comment: @AdamTucker . . . It should have the aggregated value.

Comment: My mistake I removed the ;  at the end of the sql and works fine!!  You legend!! thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  SC_JOBS.CREATIONDATE,
  (SELECT SUM(SC_JOBS.GROSSEXCLVAT) FROM SC_JOBS WHERE SC_FRAMES.GROUPPRODUCTTYPE = 'ATI'    AND SC_FRAMES.JOBID = SC_JOBS.JOBSID AND SC_JOBS.INVOICEDATE < '1990-01-01') AS Product 1,
  (SELECT SUM(SC_JOBS.GROSSEXCLVAT) FROM SC_JOBS WHERE SC_FRAMES.GROUPPRODUCTTYPE = 'ATI'    AND SC_FRAMES.JOBID = SC_JOBS.JOBSID AND SC_JOBS.INVOICEDATE < '1990-01-01') AS Product 2 
FROM
  SC_JOBS
INNER JOIN
  SC_FRAMES ON SC_FRAMES.JOBID = SC_JOBS.JOBSID
WHERE
  SC_JOBS.CREATIONDATE BETWEEN :StartDate AND :EndDate
GROUP BY
  SC_FRAMES.GROUPPRODUCTTYPE
ORDER BY
  SC_JOBS.CREATIONDATE
```

Comment: It wouldnt run the query :-(

Comment: Engine Code    : 335544569
Engine Message :
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Invalid expression in the select list (not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause)

Comment: If I put the inner join in each of the sub select statements it works, but is very slow

Answer (score 0):

Add `GROUP BY SC_FRAMES.GROUPPRODUCTTYPE` after the end of your `WHERE` statement and before your `ORDER BY` statement. Also change your `AS` values to not include spaces as I've encountered ploblems with this in the past, so use `Product1` as opposed to `Product 1`

Comment: If I put the inner join in each of the sub select statements it works, but it is far too slow.

Comment: @AdamTucker if it works that's the main thing isn't it? Speed could be anything from the server capacity to the number of records being stored

Comment: true - but there about another 50 sub statements ,this just shows an example